# git rebase already rebased branch

Tags: git

I have following structure:

```
F2:                      [F21] - [F22] - [F23]
                        /
F:       [F1] - [F2] - [F3] - [F4] - [F5]
        /
M: [M1]
```

And, I did squash (rebase) the commits in `F` branch, leading to following:

```
F2:    [F1] - [F2] - [F3] - [F21] - [F22] - [F23]
      /
M:   [M1]
      \
F:     [F']
```

And merged to master:

```
F2:    [F1] - [F2] - [F3] - [F21] - [F22] - [F23]
      /
M:   [M1] - [M2]
      \    /
       [F']
```

Now, I want to basically rebase `F2` to `F`, but that requires me to resolve conflicts along the path, mainly `F1`, `F2`, `F3` with `F'`. My desired result is:

```
F2:    [F`] - [F21] - [F22] - [F23]
      /
M:   [M1] - [M2]
      \    /
       [F']
```

Is it possible to somehow hint rebase, that changes it is seeing are part of commits I have, so I don't need to resolve them?

Comment: That's what you get when you squash commits. Honestly, don't do it. You'll be glad you didn't when you need to fix your next regression and are able to use `git bisect` to good effect.

Comment: Since it's not an answer to your question, I'll leave it as a comment: I believe your last image wants to display the arrow from M1 to the F2 timeline, right? And sorry, and then you seem to want to squash `F1...F3` inside the `F2` history. I'm afraid you're out of luck - you can't "hint" anything anymore since you squashed those `F` commits, and I see no use at all for squasing `F1...F3` again. Sqashing is one of the few things which really loses you information, so... out of luck. It has use for cleaning up unpushed feature branches just before a push, but that's not what you have here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to tell rebase to skip those commits with the `--interactive` flag. On F2, do:

```
git rebase --interactive [F']
```

You will see what git is preparing to do:

```
pick c411f13 F1    // <- delete this line or use drop instead of pick
pick 8f9b902 F2    // <- delete this line or use drop instead of pick
pick 7693586 F3    // <- delete this line or use drop instead of pick
pick 1fd0615 F21
pick 26fd795 F22
pick 2fb0408 F23
```

See the comments below these lines for more informations, `# d, drop = remove commit` and `# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST` are interesting here.

Save and quit, git will do what you asked: skip the first commits and apply the others.